# How to remove groups if rows within a specific group do not follow an ascending sequence?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I was wondering how to filter out groups in which rows do not follow a complete, ascending sequence:

```
Example

Animal    Count
Dog       4
Dog       5
Dog       6
Dog       7
Cat       11
Cat       13
Cat       14
Cat       15
Rat       9
Rat       10
Rat       11
Rat       12
Rat       14
Moose     17
Moose     18
Moose     19
Moose     20
```

The resulting dataframe should look as below:

```
Animal    Count
Dog       4
Dog       5
Dog       6
Dog       7
Moose     17
Moose     18
Moose     19
Moose     20
```

Here, the preceding row values are all one more than its previous row value. I've tried combining conditional statements with dplyr package, but I've been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach is to calculate the difference between consecutive rows within each group and check if all of them are equal to 1. Assuming your data is in `df`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Animal) %>%
  filter(all(diff(Count) == 1))

#   Animal Count
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 Dog        4
# 2 Dog        5
# 3 Dog        6
# 4 Dog        7
# 5 Moose     17
# 6 Moose     18
# 7 Moose     19
# 8 Moose     20
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did not realize "diff" was so handy.

Comment: It is :) Check out http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Vocabulary.html for a nice list on useful base R functions.